# React UseState Set function loses value after API call

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a search button which when clicked calls an API. Upon successful response, I set the state for a few elements (say a, b, c textboxes) on the page, and then it calls another API. Upon successful response of the second API, I set the state for a few other elements (say d, e textboxes) on the page. The state object is the same between the two API calls and I can't split them up without heavy refactoring.

The behavior I am noticing is that after the first API call is returned and the first set state function is called I see the elements a, b, c on the page update correctly. But after the second API call is returned and the second set state function call is made, the elements a, b, c lose the previous value.

I am using the previousState in my set function so I am not really sure why that is happening. I have verified that if I remove the second API call, the state values persist correctly.

Here is my code for child component

```
    const handleSearchClick = () => {
    myService.getInfo(Input)
        .then((response) => {
            let updatedData = []; 
            updatedData.push({
                key: "a",
                value: "Value For A"
            });
            updatedData.push({
                key: "b",
                value: "Value For b"
            });
            updatedData.push({
                key: "c",
                value: "Value For C"
            });

            if (props.handleChange) {
                props.handleChange(updatedData);
            }

            callSecond();
        }
   }

const callSecond = () => {
    myService.getMoriInfo(Input)
        .then((response) => {
            let updatedData = []; 
            updatedData.push({
                key: "d",
                value: "Value For D"
            });
            updatedData.push({
                key: "e",
                value: "Value For E"
            });

            if (props.handleChange) {
                props.handleChange(updatedData);
            }
    }
}
```

and my parent component has following:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    isReadOnly: true,
    isLoading: true,
    a: null, 
    b: null,
    c: null, 
    d: null, 
    e: null,
  });

...
 
    const handleChange = (item) => {
      let newData = {};
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
          newData = {
            ...newData,
            [item[i].key]: item[i].value,
          };
        }

    setData(previousData => ({
      ...previousData,
      ...newData
    }));
    }
```

I have read that for this type of stuff I should be setting state in useEffect but I am not sure how.

Comment: Is this an accurate [mcve]? Where are the API calls? Where is the other state update?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usestate-set-function-loses-value-after-api-call-3rfxn1) and it seems the state updates fully. I can't reproduce the issue as described. Please feel free to fork the sandbox and see if you are able to add more of your code and reproduce the issue. If you can, please edit your post to include the new details and link to sandbox so that we can inspect and debug it live.